# Enso application crashes

Tags: windows-7, crash, launcher, launchy

I've been a fan of enso http://www.humanized.com/enso/ for quite a while, but for the past several years I've had problems with it crashing, I've never been able to get it work reliably with Windows 7. Has anyone had any luck with this? I've tried the open source edition but it hasn't been any better (when I can get it to install at all) and development is moving pretty slowly. Has anyone had any luck getting enso to work reliably on Vista or 7?

Comment: Are you using 32 or 64 bits Windows 7?

Comment: 64 bit, woe is me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - I think I've cracked it (partially).

If I disconnect my (physical) LAN connection before starting enso, it launches fine. Then I can plug my LAN back in and all is well.

Perhaps there's a fault in some "phone home" logic that is bypassed when the connection is down?

I suspect perhaps changing the windows 7 rules/permissions may help, but I've not had time to test.

G

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.launchy.net/

> Launchy is a free cross-platform utility designed to help you forget
>   about your start menu, the icons on your desktop, and even your file
>   manager.
>
> Launchy indexes the programs in your start menu and can launch your
>   documents, project files, folders, and bookmarks with just a few
>   keystrokes!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have used Launchy in the past and would suggest it if I didn't know Enso, but now I don't want to switch away from Enso as it works so intuitively and can do more. Even with the Windows 7 search I end up using Enso more than it and I have installed Enso yesterday.