# Humanized Enso on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, launcher

I know this may be the same topic as in the [previous post](https://superuser.com/questions/127098/enso-application-crashes), but because there was no reliable answers there and it's been very long time ago, so I would like to ask again here and hoping someone could help me.

I've been using [humanized enso](http://humanized.com/enso/) for almost three years now. At the beginning, enso worked fine on windows 7, but suddenly about last week, I realized that enso wouldn't work anymore. It started to crash every time I tried to start it. **Is there anyone who has the solution for this?** Because it seems that the enso project has been stopped and there is no more support for the user.

thank you...

Comment: Make it more clear what do mean by "Solution for this", Are you looking for an alternative to this ?

Comment: Wow... it's been a long time I haven't joined this topic. The 'solution' I was looking for is how to make enso working in windows 7? or what should I check to understand the problem occured? I've tried some of the alternatives, but haven't found one as good as enso.

Comment: I know this post is very old, but I've had the exact same problem.  I like the idea of finding application by name, but 95% of the time I get an error because it has crashed.  Usually it's after Windows has been open for a couple of days.  If I restart Enso or restart the computer it is working again, but that's very annoying.  I've posted a bug to the Enso site and no response... so sadly it looks out of development.